# declaring and invoking constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Below code shows error at **line 4**

```
class MyClass{

    public MyClass(int a){ } //Line 2

    public static void main(String a[]){
        MyClass n = new MyClass(); //Line 4
        System.out.print("TRUE");
    }
}
```

But, once i remove **line 2**, it runs without any error. Although, I didn't add default constructor. Why ?

Comment: The default constructor is added if and only if you don't provide one.

Comment: The default constructor also disappears when you provide one.

Comment: its a basic question, if you use IDE you can come through why its throwing the error.

Comment: yeah, i know, there is an error. that's why i wanna know.. background of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `Compiler` provides your class with a `default constructor` only if you have not given any explicit constructor. As soon as you declare your own constructor, parameterized or 0-arg, the compiler won't give you the default constructor.

Now in your code, you have declared a parameterized constructor, compiler won't give a default one. So, you actually don't have any 0-arg constructor, and hence you cannot use it.

> once i remove line 2, it runs without any error. Although, I didn't
>   add default constructor. Why ?

Of course if you remove your *line 2*, then you haven't declared any explicit constructor, in which case *Compiler* adds a default 0-arg constructor, and hence your code succeeds. Also note that the *default constructor* is the one give by compiler. When you declare your *0-arg constructor*, it's not called a *default* one, but just a *0-arg constructor*.

So, whenever you are declaring a parameterized constructor, make sure that you also declare a `0-arg constructor` explicitly, if of course you are using it.

```
public MyClass() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each class will have an *implicit* default constructor, which takes no arguments. However, when you declare a constructor with args, the default constructor is omitted. Hence

```
MyClass n = new MyClass();
```

will fail to compile.

Note that a class can have *multiple* constructors, and you can declare the default no-arg constructor *explicitly* if you have other constructors. e.g.

```
class MyClass{
    public MyClass(int a){ } 
    public MyClass(String a){ } 
    public MyClass(){ }  // no-arg declaration now required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because once you declared a constructor with parameters, the default constructor without parameters is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

In your class default constructor is missing , it contains only parameterised constructor. But you are initializing using default constructor. So you will get error at line 4. 
Add default constructor too in your code as blow

as your creating object with default constructor `MyClass n = new MyClass();`  your code should have default constructor.

```
public MyClass(){ }
```

now it will work with out any error.

If you want to go with paramertised constructor, then create object as below.

```
MyClass n = new MyClass(pass parameter here);
```

Comment: i believe... you didn't get my question.

Comment: my answer make sense to your question

Answer (score 0):

if you have no constructors defined in the class then ***only*** compiler will automatically insert default constructor (no-args)
Read the last paragraph at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

When you create parameterized cunstructor then default constructor is removed unless you create you own default constructor.

Hence you have to create constructor as below.

```
public MyClass(){}
```